# General question about adequacy of logical connectives

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Sorry, perhaps a somewhat vague (or: too large) question, but I wonder if there is a general method for determining whether some statement containing certain logical connectives can or cannot be expressed using some other (single) connective. For instance, $A ∨  B$ can be expressed in terms of ⇒ alone (indeed, it is logically equivalent to $(A ⇒ B) ⇒ B$, but $A ∧ B$ cannot (supposedly). Nor can $A ∧ B$ be expressed using ⇔ alone (supposedly). The cases where it is possible are obviously easier, as we need only find a matching truth table. I've seen some proofs for the cases where it cannot be done, but they don't really approach it systematically. Is there a systematic way to go about this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%27s_lattice